# If $x$ and $y$ are transcendental, then $\left \{x,y\right \}$ is algebraically independent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

I have $x$ and $y$ transcendental over a field extension $E/K$, and I have to prove (or disprove) that $\left \{x,y\right \}$ is algebraically independent.

I was able to prove that $\left \{x',y'\right \}$ is algebraically independent over $K$ if $x'$ is transcendental over $K$ and $y'$ is transcendental over $K(x')$ (not $K$). Maybe if I could prove that $y$ is transcendental over $K(x)$ I would be done, but I do not know how to prove it. Maybe that it is not even true.

Comment: What is $x'$? $\phantom{}$

Comment: It is just another transcendental number over $K$. (I did not want to use "$x$" and "$y$" again to state what I was able to prove).

Comment: What about $x=\pi$, $y=2\pi$? Both are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ but they are not algebraically independent.

Comment: Or for that matter, $x=y=\pi$....

Comment: Or $x=e$ and $y=e^2$... They are both trascendental and trivially algebraically dependent.